# How to get all data from Redis or speed up calls?

Tags: ruby, redis

Maybe this is a question for code review, but I think it's best suited here.  Let me know if it needs to be moved.

I'm using Redis as what amounts to a long-term cache for some data in a Sinatra application.  I'm iterating over all of the keys in Redis, pulling their data, and parsing it with JSON.  It's taking quite a bit of time.  here's the benchmark:

```
[13] pry(main)> Benchmark.measure do
[13] pry(main)*   dkeys = redis.keys.delete_if {|e| e == "last_run"}  
[13] pry(main)*   @delayed = dkeys.map {|k| {k => JSON.parse(redis.get(k))}}                                                                                                         
[13] pry(main)* end  
=>   0.520000   0.160000   0.680000 (132.410716)

[14] pry(main)> @delayed.count
=> 1358
[15] pry(main)>
```

The delay is clearly in the map and I think the latency is the cost of calling redis 1300+ times.

Is there a way that I can pull all of the data from redis into an object so I won't have to call it on each step of the iteration?

Comment: can you not just cache what you are getting out of the each?

Comment: that seemed a little heavy handed given the scope of the application, but i may have to just go that route.

Comment: You should look at this if you haven't already: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10155398/getting-multiple-key-values-from-redis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take a look at the answer @peterpan refers to. In particular, `mget` should do the trick:

```
dkeys = redis.keys.delete_if {|e| e == "last_run"}
@delayed = redis.mget(dkeys).map {|s| JSON.parse(s)}
```

Comment: This one runs substantially faster (finishes in just over 1 second) and gets me 90% there.  @peterpan's comment was incredibly helpful as well.

Comment: Good to hear -- I see now that you actually wanted a map with key => (JSON parsed) value. I'm not so well versed in Ruby, sorry about that but glad that the answer was helpful!

Comment: Yeah, I'm using Array#zip to kind of mangle a Hash together right now  with some success.  At any rate, the answer worked quite well.